# Datatype for "NaN" in validation process

Tags: jquery

Goal:
Evaluate a specifik value in my validation code

Problem:
The variable "currentValue" can retrieve a value named "NaN". And i don't know what kind of datatype that shall be applied in the my validation process.

Based on my previous test, NaN is neither a string or int or something similiar.

What datatype is NaN?

```
    var ddd = $('#field_timmar').val();
    //datac= $('#field_timmar').val();
    //len = currentValue.length;

    var currentValue = parseInt(ddd);


    // Validating message
    if(currentValue <= 0)
    {
        $('#field_timmar_error1').show();

        $('#field_timmar_error2').hide();
        $('#field_timmar_error3').hide();

        nonError = false;
    }
    else if(currentValue == "NaN" && ddd != "")
    {
        $('#field_timmar_error2').show();

        $('#field_timmar_error1').hide();
        $('#field_timmar_error3').hide();

        nonError = false;
    }
    else if(currentValue == "NaN" && ddd == "")
    {
        $('#field_timmar_error3').show();

        $('#field_timmar_error1').hide();
        $('#field_timmar_error2').hide();

        nonError = false;
    }       
    else
    {
        $('#field_timmar_error1').hide();
        $('#field_timmar_error2').hide();
        $('#field_timmar_error3').hide();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data type of NaN is actually Number, but because of its special status, it cannot be directly compared with any other value. There is a function [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) that lets you test whether a number is NaN:

```
if (isNaN(currentValue)) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NaN is a Number which is NaN. When cast to a String, it generally outputs "NaN", but it does not equal "NaN". NaN equals nothing, including NaN.

Simple enough for you?

The easiest way to test for NaN is the method `isNaN`.

```
console.log( isNaN( Number( "quack" ) ) ) // true
console.log( isNaN( Number( "1" ) ) ) // false
```

I once encountered an implementation glitch where NaN where generated through bad concatenation: 1 + "threeve" when what is wanted is "1" + "threeve", other times it is through situations like exampled above, or situations like the following:

```
// value is undefined
var obj = {}
console.log( 1 + obj.notDefinedProperty )
var arr = []
console.log( 1 + arr[ 1 ] )

// non-castable
var obj = {}
obj++;// also works for +=
console.log(obj)
"string" * 1
```

Comment: Actually, `1 + "threeve"` does not result in NaN; if either operand is a string, string concatenation is performed instead of numeric addition.

Comment: @casablanca Yes, this is true, but I have seen signs where it was clearly supposed to result in "1threeve" and I got NaN instead. It could very well have been an implementation glitch (or it might have even been another dialect of ECMAScript), but that is one of the places I check when I find NaN.

Comment: @casablanca When concatenating, I generally err on the side of "Assume the worst"

Comment: That must have definitely been an implementation glitch then. And no need to assume the worst, ECMAScript's rules for the + operator are very simple.

Answer (score 0):

`NaN` means not-a-number.you can test its with `isNaN()` function:

```js
console.log( isNaN(123) );
console.log( isNaN("ABC") );
```

Answer (score 0):

Other way to check if value is Nan ?

```
value !== value
```